# Binding elements when modal window loads from AJAX (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, colorbox

I'd like to set up a drag'n'drop list inside a modal window. The window's content is loaded via an AJAX call, so I believe I need to use jQuery's .live() method.

Here is my current code:

```
$('#cboxLoadedContent').live('load', function() {
    // Event for sortable page lists
    $('ul#pageList').sortable();
});
```

How can I set up bindings when the modal window loads? The modal window comes from the colorbox plugin.

Note: I'm guessing that `'load'` is not the right event to use, because if I throw a simple `alert()` in there, it doesn't even show up when the window loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, just call `.sortable()` on the elements when you're loading them via ajax, like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'page.html',
   //stuff...
   success: function(data) {
     //Put stuff in DOM
     $('ul#pageList').sortable();
   }
});
```

For the **why** part: `.live()` doesn't work this way, it doesn't wait for new elements and do things...it listens for events from elements that bubble up the DOM then executes event handlers if it has a selector that matches.

Comment: Ah, I had to add the .sortable() binding to the `onComplete:` attribute of the Colorbox. Thank you for the explanation of why `.live()` did not do the job as well. That clears up a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which modal window are you using.

If you are using the [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-open), you can use the `opendialog` event.

So you can bind a function to that event that is triggered when the dialog open.

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "dialogopen", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

If you are not using the jQuery UI, you have to go to the code and look if some event is triggered when the popup opens.

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately. I had to add the binding to the `onComplete` attribute of my Colorbox.