# Which Jquery events should I use within an ajax modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a modal loaded via AJAX, I use .on() JQuery to bind events inside that modal :

```
    $(document).on('click', '#myButton', function() {  
        $('#myDiv').toggle();
    });
```

I want to toggle() that div when the modal is called, which event should I use ?

I tried "load" but it doesn't works :

```
    $(document).on('load', function() {  
        $('#myDiv').toggle();
    });
```

edit :

I found a solution here : [Binding elements when modal window loads from AJAX (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543468/binding-elements-when-modal-window-loads-from-ajax-jquery)

Comment: Try $('#myButton').click(function() { $('#myDiv').toggle(); });

Comment: I'm sorry maybe my question is not clear :  I don't want to click, the click works, this is an example. I want $('#myDiv').toggle(); fire when my modal is loaded.

Comment: how is your modal working ? is it a plugin ? your own custom code ? depending on that, it could be the modal responsability to fire an event when content is loaded or you could plug yourself to some callback once ajax response return

Comment: if the modal is loaded through ajax, why don't you use the ajax's success function as a callback to toggle it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#myButton').click(function() { 
    $('#myDiv').toggle(); 
});
```